# C++ define class in head file, and implement its member in source file

Tags: c++

when i build this project in vs2010, error occurs:

1. syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'b'
2. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does
   not support default-int
3. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note:
   C++ does not support default-int
4. error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier

   ```
   #ifndef _B_H
   #define _B_H

   #include <string>

   class B
   {
   public:
       B();
       ~B();
       void showfunc();

       string b;
   };

   #endif

   /***************************/
   // B.cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include "B.h"
   using namespace std;
   B::B()
   {
   }
   void B::showfunc()
   {
    cout<<b<<endl;
   }
   /**************************************/
   // main.cpp
   #include <iostream>
   // #include "B.h"
   using namespace std;
   void main()
   { 
   }
   ```

Please help me!

Comment: `string` is in the `std` namespace. You need `std::string b;`

Answer (score 1):

`string` is in the `std` namespace. You need

```
std::string b;
```

You should also be [be careful with `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), even in implementation files.

Also, note that `void main()` is not one of the standard signatures for `main` in C++. You need

```
int main() { ...
```

Comment: I added **using namespace std;** at the beginning of the head file B.h, and it works. It's troublesome to add std prefix everytime when using classes in the `std` namespace. But in fact i have **using namespace std;** sentence at the head of source file **B.cpp**. why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Barnett_Love You should not use `using namespace std`. It is more trouble than it is worth. You will deeply regret it one day. As to your question, putting that in `B.cpp` has no effect on `B.h`.

Answer (score 0):

add `std` to string

```
std::string b;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I added **using namespace std;** at the beginning of the head file B.h, and it works.